# Ionic & ios how to make fixed top bar button and scrollable list

Tags: ios, css, ionic-framework

In ionic with ios platform, i want the following view:

- The header
- A fixed bar button
- A scrollable list

So i have tried to make:

```
<ion-view view-title="Account">
   <div class="button-bar" style="margin-top:66px;">
        <a class="button">Item 1</a>
        <a class="button">Item 2</a>
        <a class="button">Item 2</a>
    </div>
 ...
```

When i make *ionic emulate ios*, in the iphone simulator i don't see the bar button (i think because it's behind the header bar)

So i have added a margin-top:

```
<div class="button-bar" style="margin-top:44px;">
```

Now i see but a portion of the header bar is always on top of the bar button. It's because of the status bar? Which is the height of the status bar + header bar on the ios device?

To make a scrollable list (only the scrollable list) i must add a  after the button-bar div?

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div class="button-bar" style="margin-top:66px;">
    <a class="button">Item 1</a>
    <a class="button">Item 2</a>
    <a class="button">Item 3</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.button-bar
    {
      float:left;
      overflow-Y:scroll;
      height:50px; 
      width:150px;
    }
.button
    {
      float:left;
      width:100%;
    }
```

see this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jysqs1pL/) and try to scroll your Items. :)

To make everything clear and visual do `float:left;` and `display:block;` of your every element